# Интерактивная сетка на Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qt-designer

Создаю приложение на Qt Creator, которое ищет минимальный путь между двумя заданными точками на карте. Карта представляет собой набор клеток (пусть будет 10*10 клеток), в каждой из которых может быть свой вид местности, который влияет на скорость прохождения через данную клетку.

Должна быть возможность редактирования карты с помощью GUI, поэтому решил делать ее примерно так: При открытии приложения задается размер карты (n), после чего выводится сетка с пустыми (или заполненными значениями по умолчанию) клетками (n*n клеток). Справа от сетки есть набор кнопок со всеми возможными типами местности. Редактирование сетки происходит так - нажимаем на интересующую нас клетку, а затем выбираем из правого меню нужный тип местности, после тип местности в клетке меняется на выбранный нами в меню (под изменением типа местности подразумеваю изменение некого численного параметра в соответствующем элементе матрицы, хранящей информацию обо всех клетках карты и изменение графического отображения клетки (картинка равнины поменялась на картинку горы, например)). Примерно таким образом мы сможем задать интересующую нас карту.

**Основной вопрос:** Как в QT сделать эту самую сетку, в которой клетки могут:

- быть привязанными к матрице(массиву)(а может вообще какому-либо другому формату данных, если вы знаете более подходящий), содержащей данные об этих клетках
- быть "кликабельными" и редактируемыми с помощью GUI
- отображать свое состояние в режиме реального времени.

PS: Я очень мало знаком с Qt, поэтому, возможно, мой вопрос может выглядеть слишком размытым и неточным.

Comment: В общем и целом почитать про шаблон проектирования `Model-View-Controller` MVC. Для отображения сетки рекомендую воспользоваться виджетами `QGraphicsView`, `QGraphicsScene` и серией виджетов-наследников `QGraphicsItem` (Это будет ваш View). Для хранения информации об карте создать соответствующую модель данных (информация об ячейках их типах и так далее), это ваша Model. Взаимодействие между ними, это `Controller`

Comment: Про MVC https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller